# IMessageFilter for console application

Tags: c#, com, ole, imessagefilter

My console application uses third-party (non-Microsoft) application, which provides COM server functionality. I have implemented the `IMessageFilter` interface in a way described [here](http://support.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/training/se/106/api/OleMessageFilterCS.html).

From the interface I expect that when the COM object does some task and cannot for example immediately quit on my request from another thread it would continuously call `RetryRejectedCall()` and wait until the object is free.

However, I see that it does not work as this, but throws `COMException` instead, where I try to close again and again. And after I receive `OnQuit` event from COM object it calls `RetryRejectedCall()` with value 2 (`SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER`).

My log looks as follows:

```
Info:   COM - opening project 'MyProject'...
Info:   Console_CancelKeyPress event fired.      // I pressed ctrl+c
Info:   COM - quitting... (attempt 1)            // quit() called from another thread
Error:  COM - failed to close, it might be busy.
Info:   COM - quitting... (attempt 2)
Info:   COM - project 'MyProject' opened.
Info:   COM - quit successfully                  // quit only after open operation complete
Debug:  RetryRejectedCall: dwRejectType=2
Debug:  Test run thread is being aborted
Info:   COM - quit successfully              // why quit again?
```

Questions:

1. Is my expectation correct, or does it have another functionality?
2. Should I implement `IMessageFilter` for the applications that work
   with COM objects at all? In my case it works as it was without the
   interface.

Comment: A console mode app is a very hostile place for a COM server that implements this interface.  What your log file can't show that there are multiple thread involved here, probably three.  Two of which you did not create yourself.  One is automatically created to give the server a safe home, the other you got by pressing Ctrl+C.  The sequence is not unusual, you are asking it to quit while is busy loading the project.  Can't do it.  Low odds that this works when the project is large for example, the OS will give up waiting for you to handle Ctrl+C.

Comment: Consequence ought to be the same as not implementing the interface, you might leave a zombified process behind.  Use Task Manager to see that.  Talk to the vendor/author of this component for the best advice, but a "we don't support that" response is not unlikely.

Comment: @HansPassant If the interface does not work, does this mean that I can lock the thread for each API call, since, anyway, I cannot do anything if it is stuck while the COM code execution? However, locking the thread will give me correct operations sequence (e.g. I will have single quit() call).

Comment: This lock already exists, it lives inside the server.  It is nice about telling you about the deadlock, that why IMessageFilter exists.  Using your own lock does not solve the deadlock.

Comment: Sure it does not solve the deadlock. It guarantees that no API will be called until currently executed API is complete.

Comment: Yes, but it already works that way.  Either way, you can't prevent your process from terminating too soon.  Ctrl+C is not the only problem btw, the console's Close button does it too.  Try it, use Task Manager.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your answers. I just want to check whether I do the things right. I have a class (let's say wrapper) - it is inherited from OleMessageFilter, which implements IOleMessageFilter. The wrapper contains a COM object. And my wrapper's methods call APIs of this object. Is this correct implementation?